# Find total duration inside date range that is covered by a list of ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals, date-range

I have a bunch of date ranges stored in records in a table, many of which overlap.

```
2013-03-10 10:00 - 2013-03-10 16:00
2013-03-10 15:00 - 2013-03-10 17:00
2013-03-10 20:00 - 2013-03-10 22:00
```

For my cursor I have two input dates, and I need to know how much time between these two dates is covered by the ranges stored in the above table.

For this range:

```
2013-03-10 12:00 - 2013-03-10 23:00
```

7 of hours are covered by the above ranges

Hopefully that is clear.

Normally I would post what I have tried, but I can't seem to wrangle it into an SQL query at all. The best I have is a PLSQL function call from within my cursor which loops over a couple of other cursors trying to blend the date ranges in the table together and then subtract it from the given range and its a horrible mess.

I am currently using Oracle 10g, but we are currently in the process of migrating to 11g, so I can't use anything that's specific to either version until the migration is complete.

Comment: Can your ranges span days?

Comment: Yes, they can span days

Comment: Are the minutes always zero?

Comment: The dates include minutes but not seconds and are abitrary but generally less than a couple of days long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema:

```
create table Overlapping_Ranges (B date, E date);
insert into Overlapping_Ranges (B, E) values
  (to_date('2013-03-10 10:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), to_date('2013-03-10 16:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'));
insert into Overlapping_Ranges (B, E) values
  (to_date('2013-03-10 15:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), to_date('2013-03-10 17:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'));
insert into Overlapping_Ranges (B, E) values
  (to_date('2013-03-10 20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), to_date('2013-03-10 22:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'));

create table Ranges_from_cursor (B date, E date);
insert into Ranges_from_cursor (B, E) values
  (to_date('2013-03-10 12:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), to_date('2013-03-10 23:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'));
```

Select:

```
select
   to_char(c.B, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as "From",
   to_char(c.E, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as "To",
   sum(greatest(0, least(r.E, c.E) - greatest(r.B, c.B))) * 24 as "Hours Overlapped"
from 
   Ranges_from_cursor c,
   (
      select distinct
         r.B, r.E
      from
         (
            select
               T as B,
               lead(T) over (order by T) as E,
               T + (lead(T) over (order by T) - T)/2 as M
            from
               (
                  select B as T from Overlapping_Ranges
                  union
                  select E as T from Overlapping_Ranges
               )
         ) r
         join Overlapping_Ranges o
            on r.M between o.B and o.E
   )r
group by c.B, c.E
order by 1
```

Output:

```
FROM               TO                 HOURS OVERLAPPED
2013-03-10 12:00   2013-03-10 23:00   7
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15663/12)

Comment: Thanks, I had to spent a little time hammering it into shape to fit the implementation but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you looking for?

```
SELECT MIND1,
     MAXD2,
     24*(MAXD2-MIND1)
FROM
     (SELECT MIN(d1) MIND1,
          MAX(d2)MAXD2
     FROM my_test1
     WHERE D1>'10-mar-2013 12:00:00'
      AND d2 < '10-mar-2013 23:00:00'
     );
```

see the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55459/6/0) here

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me.

```
WITH daterange AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE('2013-03-10 10:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI') AS date_from, TO_DATE('2013-03-10 16:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI') AS date_to FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('2013-03-10 15:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('2013-03-10 18:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI') FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('2013-03-10 19:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI'), TO_DATE('2013-03-10 22:00', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI') FROM dual
)
SELECT FLOOR(sum_diff)
       ||' days, '||(sum_diff - FLOOR(sum_diff))*24||' hours'
       AS hours_between
  FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE
                      WHEN date_from >= TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                       AND date_to <= TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') THEN
                           (date_to - date_from)
                      WHEN date_from >= TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                       AND date_to > TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') THEN
                           (TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') - date_from)
                      WHEN date_from < TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                       AND date_to <= TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') THEN
                           (date_to - TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))
                      WHEN date_from < TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                       AND date_to > TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') THEN
                           (TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') - TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))
                      ELSE 0
                   END) AS sum_diff -- The differences are numeric values, hence sum will also be numeric.
          FROM daterange dr
         WHERE date_to > TO_DATE(:date_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
           AND date_from < TO_DATE(:date_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))
;
```

**Note:** The `WITH` clause is used just for illustration purposes. Replace with your own tablename wherever applicable.